# Download all linked mp3 files from a website using the terminal

Tags: wget, mp3

I'm trying to download all the mp3 files from this URL using wget, but haven't had much luck. I've tried this wget command `wget -c -A '*.mp3' -r -l 1 -nd [URL]` and I've tried a few other things with wget, but none worked.

This is the link I am trying to download audio from: http://www.alharamain.gov.sa/index.cfm?do=cms.scholarsubject&schid=33966&subjid=26550&audiotype=lectures&browseby=speaker

This is an example of one of the audio files and where they are linked to on the page

```
<audio preload="none" controls="">
       <source src="http://www.alharamain.gov.sa/AudioDir2/68262.mp3">
</audio>
```

Also, is there a way I can rename the files or add a track number to the filename as it is downloaded?

If you have a suggestion on how to do with curl or some other command, that works too. Also, if you suggest I do it with node instead of bash, I'm open to that as well. Although bash seems like it'd be simpler, so wanted to use that if possible.

Comment: `youtube-dl -x 'URL'`

Comment: Doesn't work. `ERROR: Unsupported URL:`

Comment: Try a more recent version: https://youtube-dl.org/